# gasless transaction with account abstraction

Tags: gas, web3-providers, account-abstraction

With the new account abstraction 4337, I am planning to crearte a chrome extension that can support gasless tx on any web3 platform. I have a paymaster that can support transactions.

For example, I am on opensea and when the chrome extension is installed it can detect tx and allow it to go gasless using my paymaster. Is this a feasible scenario?

Answer (score 0):

In theory, yes you should be able to do that. I'm not sure if you will be able to integrate with existing wallets, or if you will need to create your own wallet app however. Many popular wallets have not yet implemented account abstraction, so we are not sure yet what kinds of tooling we will get for integrating with things like say metamask. That's something I guess we will have to wait and see.

But if you were to create your own wallet provider that integrates with walletconnect it would connect to most sites. Then build your transactions to use eip 4337 with your paymaster, and it would work.

Maybe you could also try and make a wrapper around like metamask or something, but I'm not sure how that would work.

In order for users to be using your service, they will need a 4337 wallet setup somehow. You would either need to integrate with a wallet provider that supports 4337 wallets, or create your own, in theory. Because you need to inject your paymaster into the transaction creation, since in 4337 the paymaster information is submitted with the transaction when it goes to get verified on chain.

Comment: `But if you were to create your own wallet provider that integrates with walletconnect it would connect to most site.`
Thanks. I am especially interested in this flow. How can I start with this?

Comment: I would start here https://docs.walletconnect.com/2.0/ and https://explorer.walletconnect.com/guidelines

Answer (score 0):

Biconomy, Argent and Banana all support account abstraction and ERC-4337. Banana recently featured in Gnosis safe's Hackathon and demonstrated usage of their wallet. This is the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ff5udllRy9Y
Therefore, u can decide to :

1. Use existing wallets.
2. Build a wallet that integrates AA and ERC-4337

As far as wallet infrastructure goes, Wallet technology is pretty advanced and already incorporates gasless txs, social recovery, decentralised relays and social log ins. Therefore, u could focus on the creativity of your application.

Otherwise, u can build a wallet (which arent easy) and focus on the extension api and features.